# Renaming files with spaces while keeping numbers intact

Tags: rename

I'm looking to rename a lot of files that contain spaces in the file name while keeping the string of numbers intact. The numbers are not sequential and the string before and after the numbers are not the same for all the files.  I want to make the string preceding the numbers the same for all the files.

For example:

```
100 foo_1.ext
200 foo_2.ext
201 foo_3.ext
```

renamed to

```
100.ext
200.ext
201.ext
```

Comment: Is it possible there would be any duplicate files after renaming? For example, two `200.ext`?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
for a in *.ext; do mv "$a" "${a/ */}.ext"; done
```

**Explanation**:

`for a in *.ext` - get all files with `.ext` extension in current directory;

`a/ */` - replace substring to nothing ( ${string/substring/replacement} ). This construct get all symbols after space (inclusive) and delete it.

.

Or if you have **files with different extensions** and you need to processe all files in directory, try:

```
for a in *; do mv "$a" "${a/ *\./\.}"; done
```

The equivalent with the Perl rename command is:

```
prename 's/ .*\./\./' *
```

**Example**: files

```
100 foo_1.ext
200 foo_1.ext
201 foo_3.ext
3401 txt_3.txt
```

will renamed to

```
100.ext
200.ext
201.ext
3401.txt
```

Files without spaces in filename will not be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prename` for this:

```
prename 's/\D*(\d*).*/$1.ext/' *.ext
```

For all files given, this replaces the extended regular expression `\D*\d*.*` (a number of non-digits followed by a number of digits and the rest of the name) by the part surrounded by `()`, which are the digits, and the extension.

After the question was edited, it seems the filenames start with the number, followed by the space. That makes it even simpler:

```
prename 's/ .*/.ext/' *.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

The Perl rename (not the Linux one) can be used:

```
prename  -n 's/(\d*)\s*foo_\d*/$1/g' /path/to/folder/*.ext
```

or

```
prename  -n 's/(\d*)\s*.*_\d*/$1/g' /path/to/folder/*.ext
```

Sample filenames:

```
100 foo_2.ext  
101 foo_1.ext   
200 foo_234.ext   
302 foo_2.ext
```

Results:

```
100.ext
101.ext
200.ext
302.ext
```

Info:

1. `(\d)\sfoo_\d` or `(\d)\s.*_\d`: matches your file name
2. `(\d)`: returns the digits at the front
3. `$1`: return value(s) variable in `2`
4. `-n`: used to see outcome of `prename` command, remove to make changes

See: `man prename`